# ReactJs mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having some problems with my Reactapp.
I'm trying to authenticate user and get some data from my backend, and mapStateToProps are little problem.
This is how I'm getting successfully only user:

```
 const mapStateToProps = ({auth}) => {
  const {authUser} = auth;
  return {authUser}
};
```

And this is how I'm getting that data from api, also successfully

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    serversList: state.servers.servers,
  }
}
```

Now I need to combine that mapStateToProps somehow, I tried different methods like:

```
 const mapStateToProps = ( state, auth ) => {
        const {authUser} = auth;
        return {
            authUser,
            serversList: state.servers.servers,
        }
    };
```

In that case, it doesn't authenticate user.
How to combine them?

This is my full code, without some imports:

```
import { requestServers  } from '../../../appRedux/actions';

const mapStateToProps = ( state, auth ) => {
    const {authUser} = auth;
    return {
        authUser,
        serversList: state.servers.servers,
    }
};


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
  onRequestServers: () => dispatch(requestServers())
}
}


class Dashboard extends Component {


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onRequestServers();
      }


    render() {
        const {authUser} = this.props;
        const { serversList } = this.props;


        return (
            <Row>
        <Col xl={12} lg={24} md={12} sm={24} xs={24}>
        <UserInfo userName={authUser ? authUser.name : "Guest"}/>
        </Col>
        <Col xl={12} lg={24} md={12} sm={24} xs={24}>
          <BillingProfile balance={authUser ? authUser.stanje : "0"}/>
        </Col>
            <Col span={24}>
            <Servers />
            </Col >
            </Row>

        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard)
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const {authUser} = state.auth;
    return {
        authUser,
        serversList: state.servers.servers,
    }
};
```

or

```
const mapStateToProps = ({servers, auth}) => {
    const {authUser} = auth;
    return {
        authUser,
        serversList: servers.servers,
    }
};
```

The second param of `mapStateToProps` is `ownProps` not auth.
What you need is the extracted `auth` from state.

Comment: @user10099265 could you mark my answer as correct if it works :P thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ auth, servers }) => ({
  authUser: auth.authUser,
  serversList: servers.servers,
});
```